# How to display an image with text with a Picker?

Tags: .net, combobox, maui, picker

In WPF you could use a ComboBox to display an image with text (better said any content you want) by changing ItemTemplate.
In MAUI the new name of this control seems to be Picker, but it can just display text. Or am i overlooking something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The Picker is not templated and only displays text content.  You could use a ListView or CollectionView to build your own control

Comment: Had a lot of fun with maui till now. There are some really nice new controls.. but the degradation of old ones is really annoying. Can't unterstand it.

Comment: MAUI is not supposed to be an evolution of existing Windows UI tech

Answer (score 1):

.Net MAUI don't support image in Picker. You could use ListView or CollectionView as Jason suggest. MAUI ListView has `DataTemplate` which could be used to define the appearance of each item in the ListView, such as image. Such like the following (only xaml part)

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCollection}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <HorizontalStackLayout >
                    <Label 
                           Text="{Binding Name}" 
                           FontAttributes="Bold"
                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Image  
                           Source="{Binding ImageSource}" 
                           Aspect="AspectFill"
                           HeightRequest="30" 
                           WidthRequest="30" />
                </HorizontalStackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

For an alternative for image picker in MAUI, we could use a Popup with a listview or navigate to a new page with listview.

For more info, you could refer to [.Net MAUI ListView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/listview?view=net-maui-7.0).

Hope it works for you.